# Error on mount and unmount Material UI Datagrid Component quickly. "Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component."

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid, mui-x-data-grid

I am using the DataGrid component in my React application and I am encountering an error when I try to mount and unmount the component quickly.

When performing fast mounts and unmounts of the DataGrid component, the following error is displayed in the console: "Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component."

[image: error]

I'm not performing any asynchronous operations in the component; I'm simply updating the state with new data.

The table is rendered correctly; the only issue is that annoying error in the console when quickly switching tabs or navigating using React Router DOM.

[image: console error]

I'm using the "@mui/datagrid" and "@mui/material" components in their latest version

The only issue is that annoying error in the console when quickly switching tabs or navigating using React Router DOM.

I have tried several solutions, such as using a "mounted" state to determine whether to skip the setState call, or using useRef to store the data and useState to force a component update, but none of them have solved the problem.

This is my code:

```
import {
  Button,
  Grid,
  Stack,
  Tooltip,
  Typography,
  useTheme,
} from '@mui/material';
import { DataGrid } from '@mui/x-data-grid';
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';

import AssignmentTurnedInIcon from '@mui/icons-material/AssignmentTurnedIn';
import { CustomDatagridPagination } from 'app/components/CustomDatagridPagination';

export const TemplatesTable = ({ rows, onOpenAssignationsModal }) => {
  const theme = useTheme();

  const templateColumns = [
    {
      field: 'name',
      headerName: 'Plantilla',
      flex: 1,
      renderCell: ({ row }) => {
        return (
          <Grid
            container
            sx={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', marginY: 2 }}
          >
            <Typography marginBottom={1} fontWeight={'bold'}>
              {row.name}
            </Typography>
            <Typography sx={{ color: theme.palette.grey[600] }}>
              {row.description}
            </Typography>
          </Grid>
        );
      },
    },
    {
      field: 'questions',
      headerName: 'Preguntas',
      valueGetter: ({ value }) => {
        if (value) {
          return value.items.length;
        } else {
          return 0;
        }
      },
    },
    {
      field: 'assignments',
      headerName: 'Asignaciones',
      valueGetter: ({ value }) => {
        if (value) {
          return value.length;
        } else {
          return 0;
        }
      },
    },
    {
      field: 'actions',
      headerName: 'Acciones',
      disableColumnMenu: true,
      sortable: false,
      filtrable: false,
      renderCell: ({ row }) => {
        return (
          <Grid container>
            <Tooltip title='Ver asignaciones' arrow>
              <Button onClick={() => onOpenAssignationsModal(row)}>
                <AssignmentTurnedInIcon />
              </Button>
            </Tooltip>
          </Grid>
        );
      },
    },
  ];

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <DataGrid
        columns={templateColumns}
        rows={rows || []}
        rowSelection={false}
        sx={{
          '&.MuiDataGrid-root .MuiDataGrid-cell:focus-within': {
            outline: 'none !important',
          },
          '& .MuiDataGrid-virtualScroller::-webkit-scrollbar': {
            width: '0.4em',
          },
          '& .MuiDataGrid-virtualScroller::-webkit-scrollbar-track': {
            background: '#f1f1f1',
          },
          '& .MuiDataGrid-virtualScroller::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb': {
            backgroundColor: '#999',
          },
          '& .MuiDataGrid-virtualScroller::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover': {
            background: '#555',
          },
        }}
        pageSizeOptions={[5, 10, 25]}
        getRowHeight={() => 'auto'}
        disableRowSelectionOnClick
        initialState={{
          pagination: { paginationModel: { pageSize: 5 } },
        }}
        slots={{
          pagination: CustomDatagridPagination,
        }}
        components={{
          NoRowsOverlay: () => (
            <Stack height='100%' alignItems='center' justifyContent='center'>
              No se encontraron plantillas
            </Stack>
          ),
        }}
      />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

This is one of the solutions I have tried, but it didn't work. I believe it could be an internal issue with the DataGrid component.

```
....

  const dataRef = useRef([]);

  const [forceUpdate, setForceUpdate] = useState(false);

  const [isMounted, setIsMounted] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    dataRef.current = rows; // Actualiza la referencia con los nuevos datos

    setIsMounted(true);

    if (isMounted) {
      setForceUpdate((prev) => !prev);
    }

    return () => {
      setIsMounted(false);
    };
  }, [rows]);

  return (
    <React.Fragment key={forceUpdate}>
      <DataGrid
        columns={templateColumns}
        rows={dataRef.current}
        rowSelection={false}
...
```

Comment: It doesn't look like the code you provided is throwing this type of error, perhaps the problem is in the CustomDatagridPagination code.

Comment: No, I tried simplifying the component as much as I could, and I always have the same error when mounting and unmounting it quickly.

Comment: Try to remove the initialization of the initialState and slots properties in the original version.